# Upon validation laravel sends the column name to the user

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following validation code in a controller. The problem is that laravel is sending the column name in the validation error , which is most of the time abbreviations. In this case the column name is "ans". Is there a way to show a different name to the user ?

Validation :

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'ans' => 'required|max:5000|min:10'        
]);
```

Error :

```
The ans field is required.
```

Comment: If needed, you may use custom error messages for validation instead of the defaults.  [Specifying A Custom Message For A Given Attribute](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-error-messages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to customize the attribute name you can do that; you don't have to customize the message to do this. The `validate` method takes an array of "custom attribute names" to use (4th argument), just like it takes an array of custom messages (3rd argument).

```
$this->validate(
    $request,
    ['ans' => 'required|max:5000|min:10'], // rules
    [],                                    // custom messages
    ['ans' => 'Answer']                    // custom attribute names
);
```

You should always have the option to specify custom messages and attributes with the validation methods that are available. These custom attribute names get replaced in the messages where `:attribute` is used.

If you don't do it this way you would have to create 3 custom messages, one for each rule you have defined to use for your field 'ans', since any of those rules could fail and will include the attribute name.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve with the following code.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'ans' => 'required|max:5000|min:10'
], [
    'ans.required' => 'The answer field is required.'
]);
```

Take a look at the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-error-messages) to know more.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can send custom validation message,define all 
your validation message in a variable like this
$messages = [
    'ans.required' => 'The answer field is required.'
]
$this->validate($request, [
    'ans' => 'required|max:5000|min:10'        
], $messages);
```

Thanks